# Java Collection that supports toArray() in O(1)?

Tags: java, data-structures

I looked at some Collections implementations and noticed that there is no Collection that returns its underlying array (like ArrayList) in O(1), am I right?

I need a data structure that can return toArray() in O(1). it is for read only purposes, is there anything like that?

Comment: It would only be possible if it returned the live array, which would make it completely unsafe. You'd probably have to build it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method's Javadoc specifies that:

> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are maintained by this collection. (In other words, this method must allocate a new array even if this collection is backed by an array). The caller is thus free to modify the returned array. [[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray())]

So no conforming implementation will do what you want (and I'm not aware of any implementations that don't conform with this requirement).

Note that, unless the collection has a fixed size (such as the collections returned by java.util.Arrays.asList), it's unlikely to have a backing array of exactly the right size, anyway. (An ArrayList, for example, will usually have a backing array that's bigger than needed, in order to have room to cheaply grow.)